# two jcarousellite sliders with same navigation

Tags: jcarousellite

I'm trying to create a slider similar to the slider here: 
http://www.mako.co.il/

i looked at the code and saw it's built out of two different sliders:
1. the small pictures slider
2. the big image slider, which is on top of the small one.

both sliders have the same navigation arrows, and once you click on the "NEXT" button both sliders move together.

now, i used the Jcarousele Lite slider to do this, and this is the best i got:
**http://jsfiddle.net/ZvU28/2/**

the problems i have:
1. if you click on the next button (the right one) - the "bigger" slider go crazy, and then there is no sync between the small and big sliders.
2. if you click several times on the previous button, and then on the next - it work great - till the slider reaches the end/start and then the big slider go crazy again.

so - any suggestions? is there a better way to do this? i would appreciate any help!
Thanks!